# PHP MYSQLI If one row value = 0 start use another row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello in my script i want to keep reducing for example from row 1 to row5 if the value of the "current row = 0" go to the next row.

i was able to do with 2 row's like this:

```
<?php

$select_row1 = "SELECT row1 FROM mytable";
$row1_result = $mysqli->query($select_row1);


if ($row1_result->num_rows > 1) {

    while($row = $row1_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $reduce_row1_value  = "UPDATE mytable SET row1  = row1  - 1 WHERE user_uuid = '" . $avatar_key . "'";
         $update_row1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $reduce_row1_value);
    }
} 

else {

    $reduce_row2  = "UPDATE mytable SET row2  = row2  - 1 WHERE user_uuid = '" . $avatar_key . "'";
    $update_row2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $reduce_row2);

}

?>
```

but i need to make with the 5 rows like above:

> ```
>          //   ######################## MYSQL STRUCTURE ########################
>          //   | ROW 1 | ROW 2 | ROW 3 | ROW 4 | ROW 5 | user_uuid | user_name |
>          //   | 100   |  100  |  100  |  100  |  100  | 12345ABC  |  admin    |
>          //   #################################################################
> ```
>
> hope someone can give me some tips how can simplify the code and make this work.

Thank you very much in advance <3

Comment: what do these rows represent?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use an array with the row names that you want update. If someone of these rows have a valid value you will update this row. And in the case that you need add more rows you only need set a new value in the array.

Maybe in a future you need use a row name and a value that you want validate. In this case you can use the array with [$key => $value] and $key can be the row name and $value the value that you need validate.

I suppose that you want validate all rows if you want to stop the iteration when a row it's fixed or continue you can add a `break` in the if when finish the bucle `while`.

I hope that this code can help you.

```
<?php

$rowNames = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'];

foreach ($rowNames as $rowName) {
    $selectRow = "SELECT $rowName FROM mytable";
    $rowResult = $mysqli->query($selectRow);    

    if ($rowResult->num_rows >= 1) {
        while($row = $rowResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            $reduceRowValue  = "UPDATE mytable SET $rowName  = $rowName  - 1 WHERE user_uuid = '" . $avatar_key . "'";
            $updateRow = mysqli_query($mysqli, $reduceRowValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   foreach($xlsxno as $row)
        {
            if($row[0] == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array(
                'no' => $row[0],
                'name' => $row[1]
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just add your explanation. It will be more useful.!